# Large Data Analytics

Tags: python, database, bigdata, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I'm trying to analyze a large amount of GitHub Archive Data and am stumped by many limitations.

So my analysis requires me too search a 350GB Data set. I have a local copy of the data and there is also a copy available via Google BigQuery. The local dataset is split up into 25000 individual files. The dataset is a timeline of events.

I want to plot the number of stars each repository has since its creation. (Only for repos with > 1000 currently)

I can get this result very quickly using Google BigQuery, but it "analyzes" 13.6GB of data each time. This limits me to <75 requests without having to pay $5 per additional 75.

My other option is to search through my local copy, but searching through each file for a specific string (repository name) takes way too long. Took over an hour on an SSD drive to get through half the files before I killed the process.

What is a better way I can approach analyzing such a large amount of data?

Python Code for Searching Through all Local Files:

```
for yy in range(11,15):
                    for mm in range(1,13):
                        for dd in range(1,32):
                            for hh in range(0,24):
                                counter = counter + 1
                                if counter < startAt:
                                    continue    
                                if counter > stopAt:
                                    continue
                                #print counter
                                strHH = str(hh)
                                strDD = str(dd)
                                strMM = str(mm)
                                strYY = str(yy)
                                if len(strDD) == 1:
                                    strDD = "0" + strDD
                                if len(strMM) == 1:
                                    strMM = "0" + strMM
                                #print strYY + "-" + strMM + "-" + strDD + "-" + strHH
                                try:
                                    f = json.load (open ("/Volumes/WD_1TB/GitHub Archive/20"+strYY+"-"+strMM+"-"+strDD+"-"+strHH+".json", 'r') , cls=ConcatJSONDecoder)
                                    for each_event in f:
                                        if(each_event["type"] == "WatchEvent"):
                                            try:
                                                num_stars = int(each_event["repository"]["watchers"])
                                                created_at = each_event["created_at"]
                                                json_entry[4][created_at] = num_stars
                                            except Exception, e:
                                                print e
                                except Exception, e:
                                    print e
```

Google Big Query SQL Command:

```
SELECT repository_owner, repository_name, repository_watchers, created_at
  FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
  WHERE type = "WatchEvent"
  AND repository_owner = "mojombo"
  AND repository_name = "grit"
  ORDER BY created_at
```

I am really stumped so any advice at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You claim you were using SSD, but the path hardcoded in your python code suggests otherwise. Do you really store that 350GB of data on a SSD?

Comment: I had about 100GB on my SSD when I ran my diagnostics. The remainder of the data is stored externally. I'll move it all to my main drive to do the final analytics.

Comment: How much time does `grep -r mojombo your-directory-with-github-data` take?

Comment: are you running the same query each time? I know bigquery caches results so if you are running the same query there's a chance you won't get charge for running that query again

Comment: @liori it took about 25 minutes

Comment: @stupidbodo I'm changing the repository_owner and repository_name in my search each time.

Comment: Then I guess that 25 minutes is the lower bound of going through all that data due to your hardware speed. Now, parsing JSONs and filtering shouldn't take much time… maybe try using more efficient parsers?

Comment: @liori A more efficient parser than the built in python json parser?

Comment: Would it be wise to import all of this data into a DB and then search through that way?

Comment: @AnkushAgrawal: yep, see e.g. http://liangnuren.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/python-json-performance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem - Using a database. i imported the relevant data from my 360+GB of JSON data to a MySQL Database and queried that instead. What used to be a 3hour+ query time per element became <10seconds.

MySQL wasn't the easiest thing to set up, and import took approximately ~7.5 hours, but the results made it well worth it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If most of your BigQuery queries only scan a subset of the data, you can do one initial query to pull out that subset (use "Allow Large Results"). Then subsequent queries against your small table will cost less.

For example, if you're only querying records where type = "WatchEvent", you can run a query like this:

```
SELECT repository_owner, repository_name, repository_watchers, created_at
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE type = "WatchEvent"
```

And set a destination table as well as the "Allow Large Results" flag. This query will scan the full 13.6 GB, but the output is only 1 GB, so subsequent queries against the output table will only charge you for 1 GB at most.

That still might not be cheap enough for you, but just throwing the option out there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Exporting the 1GB table would cost $$ as well. I'd really like to be able to do this challenge for free.

Comment: There is no such thing as free. There is `Know-how` to build such system, and then there is the infrastructure to run the data. If you compare all that hassle to something like BigQuery you will find it cheap. Anyway you can try on a smaller data set, directly in BQ, and see how it goes, then you can import all your data.

Comment: To download this amount of data requires quite a bit of storage to be purchased. Even if I do manage to purhcase the storage, to search the data with the limited scope still costs money I believe. I'm looking a over 5000 queries so that'd be over $10,000

Comment: 5000 queries from a 1 GB table would cost $25, not $10,000. Saving the table would cost $0.03 if you kept it around for a whole month.

Answer (score 0):

With this question you coming to basics of programming, well described in classical "Donald E. Knuth: The Art of Computer Programming: Volume 3: Sorting and Searching."
e.g. if you want efficient searching, without need of full-scan of dataset on every query, you have to build index/hash of the data first and then use quick-search algorithms.

That what google does and that is what you have done indirectly by placing the data into mysql table, which actively uses indexes to speedup data selection.

You could use some local text-search engine, like [Whoosh](https://pypi.org/project/Whoosh/) for example. no need to invent a wheel these days from scratch).